# Enable Spell Check for Add-ins running Office 2016 for Mac

Tags: webkit, office365, office-js

When using an Add-in with Office 2016 for Mac, basic `textarea` elements do not have spell check enabled/available.

With Office 2016 for Windows spell checking works as expected (squiggly lines under misspelled words, right-click to correct).

Is there a way to enable spell checking on the Mac or is this controlled by Microsoft and their implementation of WebKit?

Comment: Interesting, I've never noticed this but I'm certainly seeing it now. Curious, does adding the attribute `spellcheck="true" ` to the `textarea` tag makes a difference?

Comment: No.

It does on Windows, but my add-in on macOS is spellcheck-less. 

While Safari does have spellcheck (without any work), and the W3 documentation on 'spellcheck="true"' says it works on Safari, Apple's own documentation doesn't seem to agree. They say if an attribute doesn't appear on the list it isn't supported...and I didn't find spellcheck:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html.

There did seem to be controls for developers implementing webkit as part of an app...which I assume MS controls.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur: do you have any way of reaching the office.js team to ask about this? Seems ironic that you can't have spell check...on apps running inside Office...that has spell check.